# Exextend python package JSONSCHEMA to bsonType of mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, json-schema-validator

I want to use [JSONSCHEMA](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) to validate mongodb schemas. MongoDb uses "bsontypes" instead of "types".
I tried this code, but it does not work. Could you help me? My code is based on this suggestion: https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/586#issuecomment-525259765

```
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import Draft7Validator
from bson import ObjectId

def is_objectId(checker, instance):
    return isinstance(instance, ObjectId)

type_checker = Draft7Validator.TYPE_CHECKER.redefine("objectId", is_objectId)
CustomValidator = jsonschema.validators.extend(Draft7Validator, type_checker=type_checker)
CustomValidator.VALIDATORS["bsonType"] = Draft7Validator.VALIDATORS["type"]

schema =  {
    "bsonType": "object",
    "properties":{
      "scan":{
        "bsonType": "object",
        "required": ["code"],
        "properties":{
          "code": {
            "bsontype" : "string"
            },
          "device": {
            "bsonType": "int"
            }

          }
        }
    }
  }

dic = { 
  "scan" : {
    "code": "hello",
    "device": 34
    } 
  } 

CustomValidator.validate(dic,schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are invoking validate incorrectly.  Try:

```
validate( dic, schema, CustomValidator)
```

However, to get it to work you have to add validators for all the `bsonType` values you are using - the example you were following only added `objectId` where you need `object`, `string` and `int`.